# How to route to next server?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, route

I must route all traffic from first server to second server and next to third server.

Like this:
server1 -> server2 -> server3

I use Debian Wheezy.
Can anyone tell how to do this with iproute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to route all trafic from a machine to another you can use iptables to match on a port:

```
   echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:1111
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could you tell how to route all trafic from all ports?

Comment: Maybe with this : iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2  ?